# Looping twice through a data structure from DB bad idea, how else?

Tags: loops, data-structures, data-storage

this is probably a more general programming question and something that has been on my mind.

I only have 1 year of experience, and recently started reading the book "Clean Code" and stumbling upon The Big 0 Notation.

These two things basically say that you should never loop through something twice (Loop inside of loop), because the performance is terrible (O(2n) if i remember correctly).

My question is this:

If i have this structure which is an array of all of the orders on my app, and inside of this array, there is an object, this object contains another array, which is the individual product that was in that order.

```
[
  orderOne: {

    products: [
     {name: "Life advice", price: 399},
     {name: "Test", price: 429},
    ],

    userInformation: {
    name: "John",
    age: 21
    }
  }
]
```

Now in order to display all of the orders in my view, I would need to first loop through the total orders, and then inside of that loop, I loop through the products array inside, which creates this double loop.

How would this be avoided? It feels inevitable that there is going to be an array inside of an array for data storing, which would always then mean a double loop.

I am trying to get better at understanding ways of structuring things instead of going head first and just writing double loops everywere.

Thank you so much for your time!

Stay safe!

Answer (score 0):

It really depends on what you're trying to achieve...
If you're just displaying the orders then does each order need to display each item all at the same time?
Would it not be more logical to display the items of an order once it is selected?
It's best to consider the scope of your data when thinking about how to manipulate it. This way, you're only handling data upon the user needing to access it, which should reduce loading/refresh times.

There will be times when nested loops are required, but many cases where it seems like it's required you can actually defer the consumption of the data until a later date when it becomes more relevant.

You could also have a separate array of products, each with an ID and then the order object just has a dictionary of product IDs and quantities. This can then be resolved into a full list for displaying fairly quickly.

Comment: Makes sense! So basically it would be better to display the orders in the first loop, and then the user can click on the specific order, which then loops through that products array in a different page? Thank you!

Comment: @CevinThomas it really depends on the requirements of the program and how you want the UI to look, but yes that is what I'd suggest for the described situation.